# Why does order not matter when adding binary numbers python

Tags: python, algorithm, binary

Came across a pretty neat solution on adding binary numbers

```
class Solution:
    def addBinary(self, a: str, b: str) -> str:
        carry = 0
        result = ''

        a = list(a)
        b = list(b)

        while a or b or carry:
            if a:
                carry += int(a.pop())
            if b:
                carry += int(b.pop())

            result += str(carry %2)
            carry //= 2

        return result[::-1]
```

For me it is intuitive to read numbers from the right to left, in which case the 1 that is carried over(1+1=10) will be from right to left as well. So why is it that reading it left to right and reversing it is the same, even when say length of strings a and b are different?

[EDIT] misunderstand and assumed why he did result[::-1] Thanks for the replies!

Comment: Why do you define the function as a member of Solution class? addBinary doesn't refer any members of the class. It's a redundant.

Comment: Yeah that's just the format given in leetcode oops

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm is **not** reading the strings left to right. It is reading them right to left.

You are reading the digits with `list.pop()`. See the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

> **`list.pop([i])`** Remove the item at the given position in the list, and return it. If
> no index is specified, `a.pop()` removes and returns **the last item in
> the list**.  (The square brackets around the `i` in the method signature denote that the parameter is optional, not that you should type square brackets at that position. You will see this notation frequently in the Python Library Reference.)

However, the resulting digits are added right to left to the string `result`, because of `result += str(carry %2)`. This is why `result` needs to be reversed at the end.

If you replace `result += str(carry %2)` with `result = str(carry %2) + result` and `return result[::-1]` with `return result`, you will see that the result is in the correct order.

Comment: I see. thanks! i misunderstood why he reversed result at the end oops

Answer (score 0):

Sure, the code could have collected the digits from "left to right", like this:

```
        result = str(carry %2) + result
```

... and then omit the reversal at the end. It would not make a difference for the output. Possibly the author considered that doing it with `+=` would give a performance gain, even when taking the reversal operation into account. In [my tests](https://repl.it/@trincottrincots/PerformanceBinaryAddition) I can confirm this performance gain.

Note that either way, the *input* values are read from right to left, as the digits are taken from both lists with `pop()`. It is only the placement of the resulting digits which is reversed.